# How to structure a simple command line based python project

Tags: python

I wrote a command line app in a single file `app_name.py` and it works. Now I am breaking it into different .py files for easier management and readability. I have placed all these py files in a `src/` folder as I see that a lot on github.

```
app_name/
    src/
        file1.py
        file2.py
        cli.py
        __init__.py
```

I have placed all the imports in my `__init__.py` The relative imports like `from .file1 import function1` are not in `__init__`  and are placed within the individual files where there are needed. For example,

```
#!usr/bin/env python
#__init__.py

import os
import argparse
#etc...

run_cli()
```

In cli.py, I have

```
from .file1 import function1

def run_cli(): pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_cli()
```

This is because when I use, on the actual command line `app_name <arguments>` then the `__name__` isnt main, so I call `run_cli()` in `__init__.py`. Although this doesn't look right, as I will have to call `src` not `app_name`

Comment: Your question is a little confusing and poorly worded. If you want to keep the `app_name <arguments>` syntax, you'll have to provide a wrapper script in your `PATH`. In your wrapper script, import your `app_name` package and call `run_cli()`.

Comment: @univerio how do I write a wrapper script in PATH? And wouldn't I have to import `src` instead of `app_name` as the `__init__.py` is in src, while appname has the readme and other stuff.

Comment: Yeah, this type of structure is for packages, not applications. An application would usually go in some kind of `/bin` directory, and while it may well use code from your own custom packages, it wouldn't be one itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you may be confusing two things. Having a `src` directory in your source distribution is a reasonably common, idiomatic thing to do; having that in the installed package or app, not so much.

There are two basic ways to structure this.

---

First, you can build a Python distribution that installs a package into site-packages, and installs a script into wherever Python scripts go on the PATH. The [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) covers this in its tutorial on building and distributing packages. See the [Layout](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#layout) and [Scripts](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html#scripts) sections, and the samples linked from there.

This will usually give you an installed layout something like this:

```
<...somewhere system/user/venv .../lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages>
    app_name/
        file1.py
        file2.py
        cli.py
        __init__.py

<...somewhere.../bin/>
    app_name
```

But, depending on how the user has chosen to install things, it could instead be an egg, or a zipped package, or a wheel, or anything else. You don't care, as long as your code works. In particular, your code can assume that `app_name` is an importable package.

Ideally, the `app_name` script on your path is an "entry-point" script (`pip` itself may be a good example on your system), ideally one built on the fly at install time. With `setuptools`, You can just specify which package it should import and which function it should call in that package, it will do everything else—making sure to shebang the Python actually used at install time, figuring out how to `pkg_resources` up the package and add it to the `sys.path` (not needed by default, but if you don't want it to be importable, you can make that work), and so on.

As mentioned in a comment from the original asker, [python-commandline-bootstrap](https://github.com/jgehrcke/python-cmdline-bootstrap) might help you put this solution together more quickly.

---

The alternative is to keep everything out of site-packages, and make the package specific to your app. In this case, what you basically want to do is:

- Install a directory that contains both the package (either as a directory, or zipped up) and the wrapper script.
- In the wrapper script, add `dirname(abspath(argv[0]))` to `sys.path` before the `import`.
- Symlink the wrapper script into some place on the user's `PATH`.

In this case, you have to write the wrapper script manually, but then you don't need anything fancy this way.

But often, you don't really want an application to depend on the user having some specific version and setup of Python. You may want to use a tool like `pyInstaller`, `py2exe`, `py2app`, `cx_Freeze`, `zc.buildout`, etc. that does all of the above and more. They all do different things, all the way up to the extreme of building a Mac `.app` bundle directory with a custom, standalone, stripped Python framework and stdlib and a wrapper executable that embeds the framework.

---

Either way, you really don't want to call the package directory `src`. That means the package itself will be named `src`, which is not a great name. If your app is called `spamifier`, you want to see `spamifier` in your tracebacks, not `src`, right?

Comment: thanks, this was really helpful. After a bit of research into what you wrote, I found this skeleton project which I ended up using- https://github.com/jgehrcke/python-cmdline-bootstrap

Comment: still... where would you put the cli code in there?